# PowerShell.Invoke() throws exception in single-file release

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I need to produce a command line app in a single exe file. It involves Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK package. I create a PowerShell object add commands and then use PowerShell.Invoke() method. On 7.0.0SDK it produces this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo.get_GitCommitId()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Telemetry.ApplicationInsightsTelemetry.SendPSCoreStartupTelemetry(String mode)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Telemetry.ApplicationInsightsTelemetry.SendTelemetryMetric(TelemetryType metricId, String data)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell..ctor(PSCommand command, Collection`1 extraCommands, Object rsConnection)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create()
   at LanguageStickRemover.SettingsReader.GitConnector(String commandType, String pathToRepo)
   at LanguageStickRemover.SettingsReader.ReadSettings()
   at LanguageStickRemover.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

On 7.2.6SDK error looks a little different:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.ExperimentalFeature' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig..ctor()
   at System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExperimentalFeature..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.AddVariables(IEnumerable`1 variables)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(PSHost host)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()
   at LanguageStickRemover.SettingsReader.GitConnector(String commandType, String pathToRepo)
   at LanguageStickRemover.SettingsReader.ReadSettings()
   at LanguageStickRemover.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It works on debug. It doesn't work on single file release so it's not a problem with a script. I use .NET6 and a latest Powershell.SDK release. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?
I invoke like this:

```
private static void GitConnector(string commandType, string pathToRepo)
        {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("param([string]$command, [string]$pathToRepo)")
                  .AddCommand("if($command -eq \"clone\")")
                  .AddCommand("{git clone $pathToRepo}")
                  .AddCommand("if($command -eq \"pull\")")
                  .AddCommand("{git pull}")
                  .AddParameter("command", commandType)
                  .AddParameter("pathToRepo", pathToRepo)
                  .Invoke();
            }
        }
```

Comment: We need to see more code. Where is ```pathToRepo``` set? is it passed in via command line arguments?

Comment: @YungDeiza I edited it so it's visible. It's passed to the function. But it doesn't matter truly. Even if I make it look like:

`ps.AddComand("Write-Output \"Sample output\")
.Invoke();`

it still would produce same error